# pointer as C++ iterator

Tags: c++, arrays

Few days ago, I saw code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void test(const int *x, int max){
    for(auto it = x; it < x + max; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    constexpr int MAX = 5;

    constexpr int x[MAX] = { 1,2,4,5,7 };

    test(x, MAX);
}
```

Besides uses of `auto` and `constexpr`, the code works OK in `C++11`, `C++` and even in `C`.

However, there is something that bugging me - the code access the element after the last element e.g. - `x[5]`. I believe in some cases this could be address violation, for example if you `mmap()` some memory and try to read memory after what you mmap-ed. Another possibility is if the array is allocated in read-only memory.

Am I correct with my assumption? I know I am wrong, but why?

Comment: No, it does not access the element after the last element. It only creates a pointer to such element but never dereferences it. This is explicitly allowed by the relevant standards (it is essential for pointer based iteration to work).

Comment: `and even in C` Nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall reading in the C++ standard saying it was valid to have a pointer to 1 past the last element of an array (in this case that would be `&x[5]`) but it is never valid do deference it.

The code shown does not appear to deference it ever (it only dereferences *it when `it < x + max`), but `x + max` is merely `&x[max] = &x[5]` which is valid according to the C++ standard, but as the code never dereferences this value, the code is fine and works correctly.

NOTE: Never try to dereference something like x[max] this is undefined behaviour in the standard, bad things can happen (a crash or worse...)

Answer (score 0):

when the condition `it == x+max` reaches, the loop is broken **before** executing the line `std::cout << *it << std::endl;`.

this is how loops operate.

1. execute the statement `auto it = x;`
2. execute the statement `std::cout << *it << std::endl;`
3. execute the statement `++it`
4. if expression `it < x + max` evaluates to true, go back to (2)

when `it == x + max`, the loop breaks on (4) without jumping back on (2) and dereference that dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

No, this code doesn't do what you say. There is no accessing of the one-past-the-end element.

It would be legal to have a pointer to such an element (which is how all iterator ranges work in C++, after all), though not to dereference it (unless it relates to `std::string`; then you're guaranteed `CharT()`). But you don't do either so it's fine.